# Error getting access token: HttpError: Not Found in github 0auth using the @octokit/rest

Tags: reactjs, oauth, github-api, http-error

I am trying to implement Github 0auth in my react app for which I used the react-login-github package & @octokit/rest

This is my component for login button

```
import LoginGithub from 'react-login-github';
import { Octokit } from '@octokit/rest';
//...
 <LoginGithub clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
                    onSuccess={onSuccess}
                    onFailure={onFailure}
                    redirectUri={`http://localhost:3000`}
                    className='group border-black border-2 p-3 rounded-full hover:bg-black hover:text-white active:bg-black active:text-white duration-300 hover:-translate-y-1 active:-translate-y-1 font-semibold '
                    scope='read:user%20user:email'
                >
                    <i className="fa-brands fa-github fa-2xl pr-4"></i> Continue With Github
                </LoginGithub>
```

This is my onSuccess function

```
const onSuccess = response => {
        getAccessToken(response.code)
    }
```

This is my **getAccessToken** Functiton

```
const getAccessToken = async (code) => {
        console.log(code);
        try {
            const response = await octokit.request('POST /login/oauth/access_token', {
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json'
                },
                data: {
                  client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
                  client_secret: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_,
                  code: code
                }
              });
      
          const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
          console.log(accessToken);
          setAccessToken(accessToken)
          // Use the access token in your application
          // ...
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle error
          console.error('Error getting access token:', error);
        }
      };
```

I am getting the HttpError

> Error getting access token: HttpError: Not Found

I am successfully getting the code from github but the getAccessToken Seems to throw this error.

I tried multiple different methods but nothing seems to work.
I am new to 0auth features.